# "easy" checksum in 8 bits

Tags: c, checksum

I am looking for fast check sum algorithm that produce 1 byte checksum.

I checked CRC8 and Adler8, but I do not fully understand the samples.

Also different CRC8 implementations give different results.

In all cases I do not need anything that fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRC's are based on a type of finite field math, using polynomials with 1 bit coefficients (math modulo 2). An 8 bit CRC is the result of treating data as a very long polynomial dividend with 1 bit coefficients and dividing it by a 9 bit polynomial divisor, which produces an 8 bit remainder. Since 1 bit coefficients are used, add or subtract effectively become exclusive or. You don't really need to understand finite field math to implement a CRC, just use a lookup table or use an algorithm to generate the CRC.

You could just add up all the bytes into a 1 byte sum, and use that as a checksum. The advantage of a CRC is that if bytes are missing or out of order, it has a better chance of detecting that.